# How to access reserved memory from my c application through UIO driver?

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux

I have a zynq board running with petalinux. The .xsa file is to transfer data between processing system (PS) and programmable logic (PL) using AXI DMA. I am writing an application in VITIS to verify. I have in `system-user.dtsi` file the following nodes, one for reserved memory and the other UIO for DMA

```
    };
    reserved-memory{
        #address-cells=<1>;
        #size-cells =<1>;
        ranges;
        dma_reserved:buffer@0x30000000{
            compatible="shared-dma-pool";
            no-map;
            reg=<0x30000000 0x10000000>;
        };
    };
    dma_proxy@0 {
        compatible ="xlnx,dma_proxy";
        dmas = <&axi_dma_0 1>;
        dma-names = "dma0";
        memory-region = <&dma_reserved>;
    };
};
&axi_dma_0{
    compatible = "generic-uio";
    interrupt-names = "mm2s_introut", "s2mm_introut";
    interrupt-parent = <&intc>;
    interrupts = <0 29 4 0 30 4>;
    reg = <0x40400000 0x10000>;
};
```

Petalinux is running in the board and the follwing confirms about reserved memory:

```
three:~$ dmesg | grep eserved
Reserved memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x30000000, size 256 MiB
OF: reserved mem: initialized node buffer@0x30000000, compatible id shared-dma-pool
cma: Reserved 16 MiB at 0x2f000000
Memory: 735864K/1048576K available (7168K kernel code, 248K rwdata, 1940K rodata, 1024K init, 120K bss, 296328K res)
hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 1 watchpoint registers.
three:~$
```

How to access the reserved memory from my application?

I expected command like

```
#define DRAM_BUFFER_ADDR    0x30000000
...
void DMA_Set(unsigned int * memaddr, uint32_t value)
{
    *((volatile uint32_t *) (memaddr)) = value;
    
}
DMA_Set(DMA_Base_Addr + S2MM_DA, DRAM_BUFFER_ADDR);
```

The above would write the starting adress into S2MM_DA register but it did not.Any sugesstion? The question may be how to combine the DMA as an UIO to the reserved memory.

Comment: That reserved memory region will be owned & controlled  by the driver that can match the `compatible="shared-dma-pool"` property.  Find that driver in the source code.

Comment: @sawdust what you mean by source code? It is my application? I haze UIO driver.

Comment: The Device Tree is read by the kernel, and used by kernel drivers. I mean kernel source.

Comment: Study **DMA Proxy Design** in https://xilinx-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/A/pages/18842418/Linux+DMA+From+User+Space

Comment: @sawdust I saw that link, they show an hybrid model. " The design illustrated on this page provides hybrid approach which uses a kernel driver and a user space application." I will read again, thank you for the link.